# Trying to calculate the angle between two points on a circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry

First and foremost let me say I am an absolutely atrocious at maths, please bear with me.

I'm trying to calculate the angle between two points on a circle, the two points being the distance the user has dragged in a certain amount of time.

This is what I have so far:

```
intervalId = setInterval(function(){

      if(p1x != undefined){
        p2x = Xpos;

      }

      if(p1y != undefined){
        p2y = Ypos;
      }


      if( p1x != p2x || p1y != p2y ){

        p1a = p1x - wheelMiddleVer;
        p1b = p1y - wheelMiddleHor;
        a = Math.sqrt((p1a * p1a) + (p1b * p1b));

        p2a = p2x - wheelMiddleVer;
        p2b = p2y - wheelMiddleHor;
        b = Math.sqrt((p2a * p2a) + (p2b * p2b));

        u = p1x - p2x;
        v = p1y - p2y;
        c = Math.sqrt((u * u) + (v * v));


      }

      p1x = Xpos;
      p1y = Ypos;


  }, 1000);
```

I'm not sure how to finish it. I have tried using the cos A = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2)/2bc formula but it's not worked out for me. I will appreciate your input on this. If I can make the question clearer let me know.

Comment: Angle between two `lines` NOT between two `points`

Comment: var v = Math.abs(Math.atan2(p1y-wheelMiddleVer, p1x-wheelMiddleHor) - Math.atan2(p2y-wheelMiddleVer, p2x-wheelMiddleHor));

Comment: I edited my comment some times, now I think it is correct

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to implement your response. What exactly does it return?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, keep in mind that most of the languages have an invert Y axis. Meaning the higher the point on the scale -> the smaller it Y value is.

As for your question, you should use arctan:

```
var angle = Math.atan((p1y - p2y) / (p2x - p1x)) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

Comment: var p1 = {
x: 20,
y: 20
};
 
var p2 = {
x: 40,
y: 40
};
 
// angle in radians
var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
 
// angle in degrees
var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

Answer (score 0):

First find the difference between the start point and the end point.

```
deltaY = P2_y - P1_y 
deltaX = P2_x - P1_x
```

Then calculate the angle using arctan

```
angleInDegrees = atan2(deltaY ,deltaX) * 180 / PI
```

Comment: But that does not take the circle center into account?